# Read from behind of 2 identicall <span> meta tags using PHP

Tags: php, dom, find

All I want is to read from an external source 2 prices, minimum price and maximum one.

This is the external source:

```
<p class="mb_05 magnify_price_stores"><span>
<span class="txt_price_gray">429,11  RON</span> - <span class="txt_price_gray">678,50 RON</span>
</span> <span><span  class="gray">(de la <b>50</b> magazine)</span></span></p>
```

I am using this code:

```
     function emag() {
 $dom1 = file_get_html("http://www.shopmania.ro/telefoane-mobile/p-samsung-galaxy-y-duos-s6102-25140344");
     foreach ($dom1->find('span [class=txt_price_gray]') as $node)
   {
   $result = $node->innertext;
   $price = explode("RON", $result);
   $prices[] = $price[0];
   echo "$prices[0]";
   }}

   emag()
```

And I am getting this: `429,11 429,11` on `$prices[0]` and `678,50` on $prices[1] 
`$prices[0]` is double!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the values into an array as you iterate though them. Replace the

```
echo "$price[0]";
```

With

```
$prices[] = $price[0];
```

the two prices can then be accessed with $prices[0] and $prices[1]

Comment: It is ok, but first price `$prices[0]` is double `429,11 429,11 ` and the second price is good.

Comment: Thats interesting, would you mind updating the question with the changed code so I can see what could be going wrong

Comment: This is the code updated `     function emag() {
  $dom1 = file_get_html("http://www.shopmania.ro/telefoane-mobile/p-samsung-galaxy-y-duos-s6102-25140344");
   foreach ($dom1->find('span [class=txt_price_gray]') as $node)
       {
       $result = $node->innertext;
       $price = explode("RON", $result);
    $prices[] = $price[0];
       echo "$prices[0]";
       }}
    
    emag()`

Comment: Remove the echo "$prices[0]"; This is causing the prices to still be displayed as they are found, after the foreach you can then echo $prices[0] and $prices[1]